# How to programatically remove notification in download manager android

Tags: android, notifications, download-manager

I have implemented DownloadManager in an activity. Download works fine. But this class will automatically create a notification which stays in status bar. Is there a way to remove this notification. Below is the code:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle(fileName);
    request.setDescription(fileName);
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION);

    firmwareZipPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + Constants.TEST,
            type + ".tgz");

    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(firmwareZipPath));
    downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

I tried giving false to `request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi`. Still the notification is shown.

Answer (score 3):

From [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setNotificationVisibility(int)):

> If set to VISIBILITY_HIDDEN, this requires the permission
>   android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION.

So you need to add permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

For more information check [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setNotificationVisibility(int))